# Multiple attachment from file

Tags: bash, mutt

Morning, I want to send email via mutt with attachment list from text file.

Here is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash
subj=$(cat /home/lazuardi/00000000042/subject.txt)
attc=$(find /home/lazuardi/00000000042 -name "*.*" | grep -v body.txt | grep -v email.txt | grep -v subject.txt | grep -v body.html > attachment.txt)
ls=$(for x in $attc; do read; done)
while read recp; do
    while read ls; do
        mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" $recp -s "$subj" -- $ls < /home/lazuardi/00000000042
    done < /home/lazuardi/attachment.txt
done < /home/lazuardi/00000000042/email.txt
```

I still can't attach file inside attachment.txt
I've try with FOR LOOP, it has same result.
How should I do?

Comment: That assignment to `attc` isn't doing anything since you are redirecting the output to a file. That assignment to `ls` is also weird (and would hang for input from stdin were `$attc` to actually have contained any contents).

Comment: then how should I write? I've try without ls with only 1 while (while read recp; do) but it has same result.

Comment: What is `attc` supposed to contain? What is `ls` supposed to contain? Why are you feeding mutt a directory as standard input? Are you trying to send one email or multiple emails? You haven't used the `-a` argument for an attachment anywhere in this script. Shouldn't you be doing that?

Comment: In attc I think, I can use contain of attachment as variable and read variable with ls variable. When I use -a argument after "$subj" then I run my script, it just output help of mutt (mutt --help). I want to send multiple email with list recipient from file, subject from file and attachment list from file. Where should I correct in my code?

Comment: Is that a set of parallel lists one line in each file that need to get combined? Or do you need to send all the subjects to all the email addresses with each attachment?

Comment: I need to send to all email address from email.txt with subject from subject.txt and all of attachment list from attachment.txt

Comment: The `attachment.txt` file contains a list of all the files that your `find` command found. The `attc` variable is empty. The `ls` variable is empty (until you fill it in the `while` loop via `read`). You read the addresses to send to (apparently) from the `email.txt` file line-by-line (though for line-by-line you should read http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). You then read the files in the inner loop and set `ls` to each file but then don't actually use `ls` as an attachment as far as I can tell (I don't know what mutt does after `--` but I don't see it saying those will be attachments).

Comment: Is `subject.txt` a single line or multiple lines? Do you send every line to each email address (one at a time) or one line to one email address (once each)?

Comment: email.txt was multiple line subject.txt was single line and attachment.txt was multiple line. I have success with email.txt and subject.txt. I only have problem with attachment.txt. everytime I send that email, the email doesn't contain attachment.

Comment: Then I'm back to I don't think you are telling mutt about the attachment correctly. How did you use `-a` when you tried it?

Comment: here is output if I use -a http://pastebin.com/W9vfd0y9 . and here is my attachment list http://pastebin.com/EPBkAuLB

Comment: You need to quote `$ls` when you use it to avoid the shell splitting words. So use `"$ls"`.

Answer (score 1):

You should place your variables around quotes to prevent word splitting. It causes a single argument to become two or more:

```
mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" "$recp" -s "$subj" -- "$ls" < /home/lazuardi/00000000042
```

And I'm not sure about reading input from a directory?

```
/home/lazuardi/00000000042
```

Assignments here don't have meaning as well:

```
attc=$(find /home/lazuardi/00000000042 -name "*.*" | grep -v body.txt | grep -v email.txt | grep -v subject.txt | grep -v body.html > attachment.txt)
ls=$(for x in $attc; do read; done)
```

Try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

subj=$(</home/lazuardi/00000000042/subject.txt)

attachments=()
while IFS= read -r file; do
    attachments+=("$file")
done < <(exec find /home/lazuardi/00000000042 -name "*.*" | grep -v -e body.txt -e email.txt -e subject.txt -e body.html)

echo '---- Attachments ----'
printf '%s\n' "${attachments[@]}"
echo

recipients=()
while read recp; do
    recipients+=("$recp")
done < /home/lazuardi/00000000042/email.txt

echo '---- Recipients ----'
printf '%s\n' "${recipients[@]}"
echo

for recp in "${recipients[@]}"; do
    for attachment in "${attachments[@]}"; do
        echo "Sending content to $recp with subject $subj and attachment $attachment."
        mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" "$recp" -s "$subj" -- "$attachment" < /home/lazuardi/00000000042/body.txt
    done
done
```

Which if Bash version is 4.0+ can be simplified to:

```
#!/bin/bash

subj=$(</home/lazuardi/00000000042/subject.txt)

readarray -t attachments \
    < <(exec find /home/lazuardi/00000000042 -name "*.*" | grep -v -e body.txt -e email.txt -e subject.txt -e body.html)

echo '---- Attachments ----'
printf '%s\n' "${attachments[@]}"
echo

readarray -t recipients < /home/lazuardi/00000000042/email.txt

echo '---- Recipients ----'
printf '%s\n' "${recipients[@]}"
echo

for recp in "${recipients[@]}"; do
    for attachment in "${attachments[@]}"; do
        echo "Sending content to $recp with subject $subj and attachment $attachment."
        mutt -e "set content_type=text/html" "$recp" -s "$subj" -- "$attachment" < /home/lazuardi/00000000042/body.txt
    done
done
```